# Laravel Login Form Path

Tags: laravel, url, path

So, I make a login form, but I realized there are problems on dealing with the path. First of all, here are my codes.

web.php

```
Route::get('/main', 'MainController@index');

Route::post('/main/checklogin', 'MainController@checklogin');

Route::get('/main/successlogin', 'MainController@successlogin');

Route::get('/main/logout', 'MainController@logout');
```

This one is my codes for checking the input with database.

```
if(Auth::attempt($user_data)){
        return redirect('/main/successlogin');
}else{
        return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
}
```

And this is the coding in the destination page after the login is success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Halaman Utama</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container box">
       <h3 align="center">Selamat Datang</h3>
       <br />
       @if(isset(Auth::user()->email))
          <div class="alert alert-danger success-block">
            <strong>Welcome {{ Auth::user()->email }}</strong>
            <br />
            <a href="{{ url('/main/logout/') }}">Logout</a>
          </div>
       else
          <script>window.location="../main";</script>
       @endif
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first path when accessing the login form is localhost/InventorySystem/public/main. The problem is the login is a success instead of becoming localhost/InventorySystem/public/main/successlogin it became localhost/main/successlogin. Please help.

Comment: try `return redirect('main/successlogin');`

Comment: "_localhost/InventorySystem/public/main_" `public` should not appear in your url. It should be the DocumentRoot of your server where files are served from

Comment: @kerbholz actually, i do not do the serve, do I really have to do the serve?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I've tried it, but still doesn't work and still become localhost/main/successlogin

Comment: Well, you'd at least need a webserver (Apache, nginx ...) or run `php artisan serve` to serve your files